# Increase Width of Datatable Excel Export

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to increase the default with of datatable excel.

**Currently, It looks like**

[image]

**I have tried :**

```
oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
         buttons: [
                    
                    {
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
                },
                customize: function (xlsx) {
  var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
  var col = $('col', sheet);
  $(col[2]).attr('width', 40);
}
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'pdf',
                        exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
                }
                    }
                ]
    });
```

**The button is working but it not setting to custom width.**

Thank You.

Comment: i also have same issue